# Display datatable content in textbox on jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, datatable

Is there a way to display content of datatable on text boxe(s) on same jsp. I did find a way to get row index from datatable though -

```
$("#example ").DataTable().find("tbody").on('click', 'tr', function () {
alert(this.rowIndex);
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve - Datatable would be on top, as use clicks / selects a row, content from the row will be displayed in text boxes below on same page for Edit / Update. 
Very new to JSP, Servlet world. A Detailed explanation with an example would be really helpful. 
Thanks you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <fieldset class="row1">
        <legend>User Information
        </legend>
        <p>
            <label>UserID *
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="userID"/>
            <label>First Name
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="FirstName"/>
            <label>Last Name 
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="LastName"/>                    
        </p>
    </fieldset>

     <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#example').DataTable({
                    "scrollY": 7,
                    "scrollX": true
                });

                var table = $('#example').DataTable();

                table.on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {
                    var rowContent = table.row(this).data();
                    $("#userID").val(rowContent[0]);
                    $("#FirstName").val(rowContent[1]);
                    $("#LastName").val(rowContent[2]);
                });
            });

        </script>
 <p><a href="UserController?action=insert">Add User</a></p>

</form>
```

Comment: I've attached the code (see above). Not sure what I'm missing